# Firebase Hosting alternative html name

Tags: firebase-hosting

Is there any way that I can change the Firebase main HTML file name? 
By default it is `index.html`. I would like to change it to something more descriptive.

Comment: I don't get the point. Index.html is a very common name for your main HTML file.

Comment: the web i am developing is an extension/add-in page for another established Web App, where I will need to find an independent host to deploy my source files. (The page will still run under the main webapp). So, there can be more than one of these pages and I will need something more descriptive in the html name (eg. my-new-page.html).